# Visual Studio 2015 C# Intellisense is not automatically selecting last used option after pressing "." (period)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

after I press the key [.] (period), the Intellisense appears but does not select option automatically.

For example, if I need to type the following:

```
coolOjbect.CoolA.CoolB.CoolC;
```

In Visual Studio 2013, all I need to type is:

```
[coolObject] [.] [.] [.] <Enter> [;]
```

But now, I need to type it like this:

```
[coolObject] [.] [C] [.] [C] [.] [C] <Enter> [;]
```

I need to type the extra [C] key in order to select the "CoolA" option from Intellisense.

Do I missed any settings? How make Visual Studio 2015 behave like Visual Studio 2013, which the option in Intellisense will be automatically selected by the time it appears?

Comment: Try pressing CTRL+ALT+Space once and see if that fixes this.

Comment: @poke Hi, pressing Ctrl+Alt+Space does not fix. By doing that, the intellisense will never auto-select any option even typing "coola".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now done using the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key. So your sequence would be:

```
[coolObject][.][TAB][.][TAB][.][TAB][;]
```

This at first looks a step backwards, but I recall that I recently found it to be an improvement. Don't recall exactly what the scenario was.

Comment: oh no.... now I have a delay of 1++ second to press [TAB]. I already get used to the old method... lets see how much time do I need to get used to it by pressing [TAB] without any delay in typing codes. Thanks for the tips, pal :)

Answer (score 2):

There are few workarounds i found

1. [Go to](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2013/08/fix-visual-studio-intellisense.html) `Tools->Options->Text Editor->C# (or All Languages)->General` and **Enable** `Auto List Members` and `Parameter Information`.
2. Execute this `devenv.exe /resetuserdata`. (As Administrator).
3. You can Press `CTRL+ALT+Space` each time after entering the **[.]**.

Comment: The CTRL+ALT+Space used to solve that problem for me (once was enough though).